# Etiquetado automático o sombreado de palabras claves

Tags: característica-nueva, formato

He notado con inquietud que muchos de los usuarios (nuevos y no tan nuevos) acostumbran a escribir inmensos párrafos en la descripción de las preguntas que realizan.

Entiendo que por la complejidad del problema, la descripción puede extenderse más de lo esperado. Sin embargo, en cierta forma esto termina haciendo *pesada*, *ilegible* un poco *tediosa* la pregunta al momento en que la leemos. Los que queremos participar en su solución.

Para poder plantear mi propuesta es necesario observar una pregunta de ejemplo. Supongamos que existe una pregunta de este estilo (que diariamente se originan muchas):

Pregunta de Ejemplo:

> #### Título: ¿Por qué no se ejecuta mi sentencia preparada en PHP?
>
> -------- Descripción ---------
>
> El problema que tengo es que la sentencia preparada que estoy utilizando no se ejecuta pero tampoco observo ningún error en el código *PHP* y las herramientas que utilizo para depurar tampoco muestran algún error. El archivo *PHP* es el siguiente:
>
> ```php
> <?php echo "Aqui el código complejo increible de ejemplo"; ?>
> ```

El dueño de la pregunta se extiende infinitamente con el problema que presenta:

> Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
>
> *PHP:*
>
> Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
>
> *PDO:*
>
> Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
>
> *MySQL:*
>
> - Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
> - Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
> - Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
> - Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
> - Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema...
> - Explicación extendida del problema... Explicación extendida del problema.
>
> ¿Podrían Ayudarme?
>
> **Fin de la Descripción.**
>
> Etiquetas: [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) [pdo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo)

Originalmente lo anterior sería la pregunta realizada por `n` cantidad de usuarios diariamente.

**¿Qué propongo yo?**

1. Al momento del usuario dar click en el botón <kbd>Publicar tu Pregunta</kbd>, el sistema antes de mostrar la pregunta utilice las etiquetas de la misma (en este caso son `PHP`, `MySQL`, `PDO`) para sombrear, resaltar o subrayar estas palabras en la descripción suministrada por el dueño de la pregunta.

   **Beneficios:** Los usuarios que quieran colaborar en la solución de la pregunta podrán utilizar técnicas como ["skimming scanning"](http://www.monografias.com/trabajos82/skimming-scanning-tecnicas-lectura/skimming-scanning-tecnicas-lectura.shtml) para leer y rápidamente comprender la pregunta. Esto permite ahorrar tiempo ya que permite realizar un bosquejo mental del problema del usuario (muchas veces, sin tener que leer las `n` cantidad de líneas de su explicación) y entonces responder a la pregunta en la brevedad posible.
2. Que exista una especie de detección de cantidad de caracteres "seguidos" (sin saltos de línea) que no tome en cuenta la sección en la que hay código por motivos obvios. Entonces, si la detección por defecto es de 300 caracteres (contando espacios en blanco) al llegar a este número saldría una advertencia o mensaje que diga algo como `"por favor escriba otro párrafo"` (se aceptan sugerencias aquí también) o que automáticamente realice el salto de línea y sitúe el cursor en un párrafo nuevo. Se reinicia el *"contador de caracteres"* y el proceso se repite las veces necesarias.

   **Beneficios:** Podríamos ver párrafos de aproximadamente de 5 líneas de extensión en vez de ver un **"mega párrafo"** de 10 líneas o más. Ayudaría al dueño de la pregunta estructurando su pregunta (dando impacto visual positivo) y ayudaría a los colaboradores que entren a intentar dar solución a no salir *espantados* por el **"mega párrafo"** que genera sensación de malgastar el tiempo al leerlo.

   Incluso a los que redactamos las respuestas también sería aplicable. De esta forma nos *obligamos* todos los de la comunidad a estructurar mejor las preguntas/respuestas. Esto automatizaría un poco parte del proceso realizado en la sección de *Colas de Revisión* y permitiría que dicha sección esté dedicada un *%80 a contenido* y un *%20 a forma* de la pregunta.

**Motivos que dieron origen a estas sugerencias:**

Me ha pasado con mucha frecuencia, en la hora de almuerzo de mi trabajo, chequear las *nuevas preguntas* y encontrarme con preguntas como la que mostré de ejemplo unos párrafos atrás.

¿Qué hago generalmente?: La cierro y prosigo a ver otra que esté mejor estructurada debido a que genera cierto agotamiento mental y cansancio visual innecesario leer preguntas redactadas de esa forma.

Pienso que no es algo que me sucede a mí solamente, sino que es recurrente en todos los que intentamos colaborar a otros usuarios en dar solución a sus preguntas, ya que disponemos de una cantidad muy pequeña o limitada de tiempo para invertir en la plataforma y se presenta la sensación de *perder el tiempo* intentando leer preguntas como la que suministré de ejemplo.

Al final este tipo de preguntas quedan en el olvido. Muchas veces, sin solución, aunque posiblemente muchos de los que entramos a ver su pregunta conocíamos la respuesta, pero en la mayoría de los casos no terminamos de leer la pregunta.

Comment: 1) Creo que para son las etiquetas, y personalmente no me gustaría que el sitio me remarque más aún los términos, pero sería relativamente sencillo de implementar en un userscript que uses si te interesa tenerlo..... 2) De nuevo, hay muchísimas recomendaciones que se muestran al momento de redactar una pregunta. Los usuarios no lo leen o no les interesa seguir esas recomendaciones, ¿por qué crees que sí le harían caso a una advertencia de este tipo? No me gusta que un sistema cambie el énfasis que YO quiero darle a mis preguntas

Comment: Por otro lado, para eso existe la posibilidad de editar (o sugerir una edición) en cualquier pregunta, para mejorar la calidad de las mismas. Pero si una pregunta está mal redactada, es confusa o una pared de texto sin sentido, eso va en perjuicio del autor de la misma... Problema de esa persona por no haberse tomado el tiempo de redactarla bien. No va a recibir la misma calidad de respuestas

Comment: Otro ejemplo: en **esta** pregunta, en tu primera versión, el párrafo 1.beneficios tenía 423 caracteres, el siguiente (donde se propone lo de 300 caracteres) tiene 583... ¿Dónde debería cortarlo automáticamente?

Comment: @Mariano Por eso dije en que se aceptan sugerencias. El problema igual está presente. Ayer entre a varías preguntas y al menos 4 o 5 estaban con esos parrafos que carecían de mucho sentido y hacian pesada la pregunta. Es cierto lo que dices que va en perjuicio del autor de la misma. Sí, tienes razón sobre los caracteres. Era un ejemplo, 5 líneas quizás es poco como para hacer el recorte al parrafo. Podría ser un plug in instalable? O quizás una característica que enciendas y apagues en tu configuración?

Comment: Interesante discusión relacionada: [Ask a question template v1 experiment results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/1983854). Básicamente, SO reconoce que la interfaz actual para preguntar ayuda poco a que los usuarios planteen sus dudas con claridad; por tanto, se está trabajando en una plantilla que guíe al usuario en esta tarea.

Comment: Ah ok. Entonces ya se está trabajando en una solución. Gracias por el aporte @fedorqui. Ya leí el link. Esta genial y lo mejor es que soluciona justo el problema que menciono. La plantilla se ve muy buena. Ojalá se implemente pronto. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: NO, ni locos.

---

Veamos por partes lo que propones. Lo que propones es que el sistema te haga mas facil leer las preguntas. Eso no quiere ni siquiera decir que van a ser mejores. Solo que van a ser mas faciles de leer. Si un usr no se toma el tiempo en armar su pregunta como corresponde, tampoco vale la pena que te tomes el tiempo en responderla. Aca hacemos algo gratis, invertimos nuestro tiempo. Lo menos que espero, es que quien pregunta, haga una pregunta ordenada y decente, haya leido las reglas del sitio (eso de, perdon soy nuevo y no entiendo, no me cierra ni a mi) y se tome el trabajo de explicarme el problema lo mas rapido y sencillo posible.

Desgraciadamente, no es algo que pasa con frecuencia, ya que los que estan estudiando o recien comienzan a trabajar quieren que les salvemos las asignaturas o sus trabajos.

Todo esto que vos propones, es generar mas ruido, al ruido que ya existe. Porque tengo que cortar un parrafo, cuando mi parrafo largo estaba perfecto? que beneficio le va a dar a quien entra por primera vez si el sistema le resalta cosas, que por mas que sean del lenguaje, el no queria resaltar porque no eran inherentes a su problema?

Que beneficios da no leer la pregunta completa, cuando es larga y compleja? asi como viste montones de preguntas largas que parecian sin sentido, veo montones de respuestas apuradas y sin sentido solo por haber leido 2 o 3 cosas de las preguntas, y no haberlas entendido por completo.

No me parece que el metodo actual para generar preguntas a nuevos usuarios sea comodo, pero tampoco me parece que esta sea una mejor solucion.

Comment: Es justamente eso. La mayoría de las preguntas que vi ayer era 1 sólo parrafo con más de 7 líneas de extensión que incluían líneas como: Por favor podrían ayudarme? Lo que necesito es .... (y luego repetía unas 3 veces que necesitaba en el mismo parrafo). No quiero decir que mi idea sea buena o impecable pero si pienso que podría rescatarse algo de mi propuesta. Porque esta situación se ha hecho común y no creo que sea buena. Igualmente tienes completa razón en todo lo que apuntas en tu respuesta

Comment: Me podrías explicar que  es TLDR? por favor? No me queda claro si es un término técnico o es jerga coloquial. xD!

Comment: too long; didn't read. es la version corta de todo lo que esta abajo

Comment: Ah ok. Muchas gracias xD! Ahora me quedo clara toda la respuesta jaja

Comment: Tengo la duda si el TLDR; va al inicio o al final, yo pensaría que por el significado sería al final diciendo algo así como "demasiado largo, ni lo leí", pero de igual forma al inicio te salva la vida. ¡Bah! solo ando divagando, ponlo donde quieras :P